# Selection in dictionary with str and int - Python

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, if-statement, typeerror

What I've been trying to do, is to sum the values of 'dictionary'. The error that I get is **'str' object is not callable**.

From my research on Stack Overflow, that happens because some of the values of the dictionary are strings. But I thought that the conditional statement that I've introduced in the loop would segregate those strings, because they do not comply with this condition. I thought of creating a new dict with only the int values the same TypeError occurred.

Does anybody have some thoughts?

```
dictionary = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':'letter c', 'd':'letter d'}

for v in dictionary.values():
    if type(v) is int:
        total = sum(v)
        print(total)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do what you are looking for in a `for` loop

```
total = 0
for v in dictionary.values():
    if isinstance(v, int):
        total += v
```

Or as a generator expression

```
total = sum(v for v in dictionary.values() if isinstance(v, int))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are misusing the sum function. v is just a number, not a list and sum sums a list. Try either this:

```
print(sum(filter(lambda x: type(x) == int, dictionary.values())))
```

or this:

```
total = 0
for v in dictionary.values():
    if type(v) is int:
        total = total + v
print total
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you want?

```
dictionary = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':'letter c', 'd':'letter d'}

total = 0
for v in dictionary.values():
    if type(v) is int:
        total += v
        print(total)
```

Your problem was that you were trying to call sum(int)
Sum is used on an list, instead it would be sum([1,2,3,5]) = 11